# Python Selenium iframe get element is not workin

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to access this iframe

```
<iframe class="iframe" title="Login or create a Reddit Account" src="https://www.reddit.com/account/register/?experiment_d2x_safari_onetap=enabled&amp;experiment_d2x_google_sso_gis_parity=enabled&amp;experiment_d2x_am_modal_design_update=enabled&amp;experiment_mweb_sso_login_link=enabled&amp;shreddit=true&amp;use_accountmanager=true"></iframe>
```

this is the code i am using:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/shreddit-app/shreddit-overlay-display//shreddit-async-loader//accountmanager-modal-dialog//faceplate-dialog/div/shreddit-async-loader/accountmanager-iframe//div/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

I am still new and trying to learn new methods, I am trying to access reddit login panel, after pressing login this iframe shows up:

[image]

I want to learn how to access Iframe windows

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
# Below line will create an object of WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Below line will switch into the iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Login or create a Reddit Account']")))

# perform required actions here

# Below line will come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Shawn, I have just tested your code and it said this:

Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //iframe[@title='Login or create a Reddit Account because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//iframe[@title='Login or create a Reddit Account' is not a valid XPath expression.

I am still trying to figure it out atm

Comment: Ok my bad, XPath expression had a typo. Please check the updated code in the answer now.

Comment: Shawn still the same issue <3, I tried getting other iframes from other websites and it worked but this one is tricky, at this point it feels like a challenge to me lol, if you can give it a try this is where you can find it on https://www.reddit.com/ it will show up after you press on the login button, if I solved it I will share my answer here, thanks for the help mate

Comment: Ok, I see a lot of `shadow-root` elements within which the desired element is located. You need to deal with `shadow-root` elements first. Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761830/how-to-automate-access-nested-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium-python

Comment: shawn thank you for sharing this, I will check it out now, was going to lose my mind for a bit on this issue lol, really glad you mentioned the shadow-root did not know such a thing exist before